# Electric field at center of hemispherical ring

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I needed to find electric field due to hemispherical ring with total charge Q at its center and I solved it by attaching one more hemispherical ring of same charge which made a full ring and we know that the electric field at center of ring is zero
is it the right approach?
[image: semicircular ring]

Comment: near duplicate of the closed https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/704258/36194 .  Note that it’s not clear what is a hemispherical ring.

Comment: i attached a diagram too

Comment: Use: $E=\frac{2k\lambda}{r}sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Comment: Suppose there are two equal point charges at $\vec r$ and $-\vec r$. The E-field at the origin is zero by symmetry. I conclude that the E-field at the origin due to a single point charge must be zero. Where is the flaw in this reasoning?

Comment: Why my answer has been downvoted ! I didn't find any reason for someone to do so.

Comment: @Spencer:  Providing complete answers to homework-like problems is against site policy.  [See this post on Meta.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to derive a general formula which will give you the value of electric field for all possible arcs (with uniform linear charge density i.e. $\lambda$).

Consider an arc of center angle = $\alpha$
Now given that the arc has total charge of Q and linear charge density = $\lambda$

[image: diagram]

I am taking reference line for angle measurement as a vertical line passing through the arc (symmetrically).

At an angle $\theta$ take an element $dq$ subtending $d\theta$ angle.
Value of this $dq$ charge will be $\lambda Rd\theta$ (using L = R$\theta$)

Electric field at center due to this $dq$ charge will be:

$$dE=\frac{kdq}{R^2}$$

**From the diagram it is clear that horizontal components of electric field will cancel each other since both parts of arc will generate equal and opposite field in horizontal direction.**

So net electric field will be in downward direction and it will be due to both parts of the arc (right and left of the vertical reference line)

Therefore,

$$dE_{\text{net}}=dE\cos\theta$$

$$\int dE= \int_{-\frac{\alpha}{2}}^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \frac{k\lambda R}{R^2}\cos \theta\space d \theta$$

On integrating you will get:

$$E_{\text{net}}= \frac{2k\lambda}{R} \sin \frac{\alpha}{2}$$
Direction will be along line of symmetry of the arc.

You can use this formula for any arc angle i.e. $\alpha$ ($\lambda$ must be constant). You can replace $\alpha$ in formula with $\theta$ for arc of angle $\theta$.

In your case value of $\alpha$ is $\pi$.